# Содержит ли данный код UB

Tags: c++

```
#include <new>

struct Test
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        new ( this ) Test;
    }

    virtual void bar()
    {
        new ( this ) Test;
        foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое "данный код"? Какие элементы этого кода следует считать ключевыми в рамках данного вопроса, а какие - второстепенными? Тривиальность деструктора `Test` - это ключевой момент или случайность?

Comment: Прочитал ваши ответы: мне доказывали, что смена объекта на который указывает this перед вызовом foo() внутри bar() - UB

Comment: А, то есть речь идет именно об этом моменте? Навскидку не скажу - надо смотреть...

Answer (score 2):

UB вряд ли (хотя пусть это подтвердят гуру в стандартах), но вот огрести так неприятностей - запросто. Представим, что `Test` запрашивает какой-то ресурс, скажем, память.

```
struct Test
{
    Test() { cout << "Выделяем кучу памяти\n"; }
    ~Test() { cout << "Освобождаем кучу памяти\n"; }
    virtual void foo()
    {
        new ( this ) Test;
    }

    virtual void bar()
    {
        new ( this ) Test;
        foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Сами смотрите - http://ideone.com/kvspoc - что получается...

Answer (score 2):

[Стандартом не запрещено](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#5), создаю, где хочу.

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor

Но как уже упомянуто в другом ответе и сказано в стандарте:

> ... the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Насколько я понимаю, проблему, указанную @Harry можно обойти следующим образом:

```
struct A
{
    A() { cout << "Alloc memory" << endl; }
    virtual ~A() { buzz(); }
    virtual void buzz() { cout << "Dealloc memory" << endl; }
    virtual void foo() { buzz(); new (this) A; }
    virtual void bar() { buzz(); new (this) A; foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    A test;
    test.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

И тогда все будет нормально

Comment: Можно даже проще :) - `virtual void foo() { this->~A(); new (this) A; }`, ну, и соответственно `bar()`...